# Add throbber to jQuery post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am displaying a throbber when I do an ajax post.  Below is how I am doing it.  I would like to make the code more concise.  Could I extend $.post to do so?  Other options?  Thanks

```
//myThrobber is an object that displays a throbber in the center of the page
myThrobber.start();
$.post('somePage.php',myData,function (json){
    myThrobber.stop();
    //do whatever
    },'json');
```

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to extend $.post to deal with throbber. It's a mixed concern. I'd rather type 3 lines of code rather than polluting the $.post API.

Comment: @LimH.  I was thinking not to replace `$.post()` but create some method like `$.postTrob()`.  Still a bad idea?

Comment: I've posted an example of how such a postThrob function could be written. It's not a bad idea per se. I just don't see too much value in doing it IMHO.

Comment: @LimH.  Thanks.  I probably will just add the two lines, but appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I'd write a `postThrob` function wrapped around `$.post`.

```
$.fn.postThrob = function (throbber, url, data, callback) {
    throbber.start();
    $.post(url, data, function (response) {
        callback(response);
        throbber.stop();
    });
};
```

So now you can use `$.postThrob` instead of `$.post`. Just pass your throbber object in as the first argument.

If you don't want to pass your throbber obj in, you can use a global variable, though less preferable. Just don't create the object inside the function itself.

I still don't see much value in doing this though ;(